# Scrolling Issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

Could someone please please help me?

My site is www.sweet.ie

I'm trying to get rid of the scrollbars as I want the scrolling to be done as per the JQuery (people keep trying to use the regular scrollbars and telling me theres something wrong with the site).

If I put overflow:hidden; in the Body style the site doesnt' work in IE 9 and below + Firefox. So i've taken it out and the scrollbars are there

What do I do? I'm not a crazy programmer, i'm more on the design end of things. Banging head against the wall isn't helping.

If anyone could help me I would really really appreciate it.

Thanks so much,

Aileen

Comment: Without the regular scrollbars, I wouldn't be able to scroll down at all.

Comment: I'm not really pro non-consistent scrolling, but did you try `html, body { overflow: hidden; }`?

Comment: I really hope that design doesn't catch on!

Comment: Removal of the scrollbars seems to be an avoidance of the real issue. Is it really best to remove a standard interface element and force your user to use your custom scrolling technique instead of just finding a way to fix the problem reported by the users?

Comment: I think being against routines is designers routine job.

Comment: Just trying to push boundries :) Doing something different to the standard navigation and pages as I want to show off more design than anything else. Its all a matter of personal preference. No need to be so harsh BonyT :)

Comment: @Beygi: There is a difference between being unique and being confusing. If users need education just to use the design (see the "Navigate by..." text on the site in question), the designer was designing for designing's sake. A good designer builds a product that caters to the user.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins yes, i agree with you, but what about the first person who designed a cellphone without any buttons, ha!...and actually i didn't say that against you i just said that to support designers.

Comment: @Beygi: In the case of buttonless cellphones, the designers were providing exactly what the users wanted: smaller phones with bigger screens. There are few (if any) examples of useful, completely new designs that arose solely from a designer's mind without a pre-existing demand. If you have examples, I am open to considering them.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins like just i said, i agree with you...about scroll-bars, i think in this example we have them too just not as user might expect, please believe me i agree with you completely...

Comment: If you can post the code you think is problematic _along_ with the live site, please flag this question for moderator attention. If your site vanishes for some reason, we have a dead question on our hands.

Answer (score 1):

Set this:

```
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Works perfectly fine in Firefox5 as well as in IE8.

[image: Firefox 5]
[image: Internet Explorer 8]

### Caution and suggestion

Inventing new technique to old already well solved *problems* maybe isn't smart. What you're trying to do is taking out a steering wheel from the car and replacing it with buttons on car doors. I don't think that's smart.

And you can as well see a different problem in my screenshots. What if users don't have a large enough screen or at least window? They can't really see your custom scroll links that would take them to other content.

My suggestion would therefore be: produce a vertically scrollable content and keep scrollbars. You can always put shortcuts in your content that would animate scrolling to new content if users want to use them. But otherwise they'd just use the scrollbar.

Comment: If I put that up on my my body the page doesn't come up in IE at all. The logo does but not the main wrap :(

Comment: @Aileen: Remove HTML, just use BODY.

Comment: @Aileen: I've attached screenshots of both FF5 and IE8. As you can see they both lack scrollbars. Put `overflow:hidden;` in your **style.css** file right at the beginning since `BODY` settings are first in it.

Comment: Hi Robert. I've done that and ftp'd up. Does it work for you in IE now?

Comment: @Aileen: It does yes. Perfectly fine in IE8 as it is in FF5.

Comment: Hi Robert. Thank you for being so nice about your answer. Not sure why people on boards have to be harsh with responses. It only takes a second to be nice and leave a good impression. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It works in IE8 but not 7 :( Unfortunately a lot of my Irish clients still use horrible 7. If I were to keep scrollbars in like you suggest: I have the wrap that contains all of my content set to overflow:hidden and if I take that out or change to overflow:visible the scrollTo doesn't work at all. Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: @Aileen: `scrollTo` doesn't work? That's strange. Most probably because scrolling the very document of your page is a bit tricky(er). How do you provide your scrollable element? It's usually the safest thing to set it as `$("html,body")`. I've also written a different [animated scroll jQuery plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html), but I don't think you can use it, because it scrolls the smallest amount. But it scrolls document without a problem even though.

Comment: Hi Robert. I've changed the css now to show you what I mean. The wrap going across measures 4300px and down measures:1590px. The scrollTo isn't working now :(

Comment: @Aileen: Why do you have the wrap in the first place? You could contain your content in the body and keep your header as `position: fixed`... Can you please tell me which file contains scrolling functionality so I can debug it and check what goes wrong and how you've done it?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following CSS property should help:

```
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If I put that up on my my body the page doesn't come up in IE at all. The logo does but not the main wrap :( Thats the issue i'm having. Its not working in IE if I use that on it.

Answer (score 0):

Set this style in your body.

```
body
{ 
   overflow:hidden;

}
```

Set this if you want only the horizontal scrollbar to be hidden:

```
body
{ 
   overflow-x:hidden;

}
```

Set this if you want only the vertical scrollbar to be hidden:

```
body
{ 
   overflow-y:hidden;

}
```

Comment: Lacks formatting. Lacks proper spelling. Lacks punctuation.

Comment: @George: Does it lack valid answer as well? ;)

Comment: Thanks for that George. Constructive criticism is always welcome :P If you could elaborate that would be great.

Comment: @Aileen Cox: The comment was directed at @samir's answer. Robert has corrected the formatting issues. Spelling is still a problem ("ur" instead of "your") and none of the sentences end with a period.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Point taken. I have removed the downvote in favor of edits.

Comment: Your criticism are accepted. I apologize for my short words. I will try to correct this in future :)